# Can you use gorilla glue to fix an Xbox 360 game disc?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

I have a copy of GTA V for the Xbox 360 and the game keeps restarting due to some problem with the disc and it is very minorly scratched.

Can you use gorilla glue to fix an Xbox 360 game disc?

Comment: Glue is not a good idea but you can get cd/dvd repair kits that will enable you to polish out minor scratches. Maybe that will be enough.

Comment: I'll also note that the gorilla glue I've used expands quite a lot once dry. Even if you could glue disks back together, gorilla glue would likely prevent the disk from fitting back into the console.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot fix physical damage to disk with glue. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc):

> CD data is represented as tiny indentations known as "pits", encoded in a spiral track moulded into the top of the polycarbonate layer. The areas between pits are known as "lands". Each pit is approximately 100 nm deep by 500 nm wide, and varies from 850 nm to 3.5 µm in length

As you see matters are too small to operate without special equipment.